# hashmap не сохраняется результат

Tags: java, android

Подскажите в чем проблема. Пытаюсь работать с коллекцией `HashMap`, и при обновлении коллекции из меню не происходит "чекнутых" позиций. Сначала в хэшмап загоняю значения из стрингового массива, который определен в `Strings.xml`. Потом эту коллекцию меняю из меню. Но она как будто статичная. Что делаю не так?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
HashMap regionMap = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
List<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<String>();
AssetManager assetManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] regionsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RegionsArray);
    for (String region:regionsArray)
        regionMap.put(region,true); // fill in array of regions by default
    reset();
public void reset(){
    assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    filenameList.clear();
    Set<String> regions = regionMap.keySet();
    try{
            for (String reg : regions) {
                if (regionMap.containsKey(reg)) {
                String[] paths = assetManager.list(reg);
                for (String str : paths) {
                    filenameList.add(reg + "-" + str.replace(".jpg", ""));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("LOG", e.toString());
    }

    flagcounter = 1;
    while (flagcounter<=filenameList.size()){
        int index = rd.nextInt(filenameList.size()); 
        String filenameIndex = filenameList.get(index);
        if (!quizCountiesList.contains(filenameIndex)){
            quizCountiesList.add(filenameIndex); 
            ++flagcounter;
        }
    }
    loadNext();
}
```

Меню:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,ChoisesMenu,Menu.NONE,"Choise");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,RegionsMenu,Menu.NONE,"Regions");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,LogOut,Menu.NONE,"LogOut");
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case ChoisesMenu:
            final String[] possibleChoises = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guesseslist);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Make your choice");
            builder.setItems(R.array.guesseslist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    guessRows = Integer.valueOf(possibleChoises[which]) / 3;
                    reset();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog choiseDialog = builder.create();
            choiseDialog.show();
            return true;
        case RegionsMenu:
            final String [] regionNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RegionsArray);
            boolean[] regionsEnabled = new boolean[regionMap.size()];
            for (int i=0;i<regionsEnabled.length;i++)
                 regionsEnabled[i]=regionMap.containsKey(regionNames[i]);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertbuilder.setTitle("region choice");
            alertbuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(regionNames, regionsEnabled, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    //включение-выключение чекнутого 
                    regionMap.put(regionNames[which], isChecked);
                }
            });
            alertbuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    reset();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog regionsDialog = alertbuilder.create();
            regionsDialog.show();
            return true;
        case LogOut:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                finishAffinity();
            }
            else
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Не понятно где и что у вас не работает. У вас какой-то список, берущий данные из regionMap?

Comment: Да, при создании активити список заполняется. Затем из настроек меню я пытаюсь изменить этот список, но он не меняется. Вот тут regionMap.put(regionNames[which], isChecked); Как предположение очистить hasmap и заполнить его заново, но почему так не работает?

Comment: а где Ваш regionMap заполняется?

Comment: исправил код, сам массив довольно прост: region, true;

Comment: У вас точно обновляется UI после изменения списка? Мне кажется что дело именно в обновлении интерфейса.

Comment: Немножко не понял, что за обновление? Я вызываю reset из пункта меню, чтобы список перестроился. Активити при этом остается тем же самым.

Comment: Вам надо бы еще сам список на экране обновить. Уведомить что ему перерисоваться надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно добавить сброс всех значий из коллекции. 
В моем случае - regionmap.clear(), а уже после этого задавать новые значения из меню.